# excel- applying a function to the selected cells

Tags: excel

Is it possible to select a range of cells in excel- A1:B10 and then log everything in the cells?

I have too many cells to go through each and manually enter `=` and `log` in each cell.

thanks

Comment: i'm not really sure what you mean by "log everything in the cells." Do you mean replace the contents of the cells with the log of the values in the respective cells?

Comment: yes, so if i have 10,100,1000 in different cells, I don't want to go through each one and add =log(), nor do i want to do =LOG(Sheet1!A1). 

and is it possible to extend this ability (if the ability does exist. e.g. multiply everything by 2 etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter values into all cells in the selection by typing the required text and pressing `Ctrl-Enter`.

### Update

I can't think of any easy way to automate putting those formulas in except by using a macro. If you just want the values, then you can create a second range next to the original with the log values and then use copy and paste special (values) to copy the values over only.

Comment: Thanks, but with that, you remove what was previously in the cells. I need to keep what is already in the cells but I want the log of those values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native Excel way to do this, but you have two options:

1. Buy a third party plugin (such as [ASAP Utilities](http://www.asap-utilities.com/)); or
2. Create a simple macro that applies a formula to all selected cells:

```vb
Sub ApplyLogToSelectedCells()
        For Each cell In Selection
            cell.Value = Log(cell.Value)
        Next cell
End Sub
```